# Prolog Tail Recursive procedure to count uninstantiated variables in list

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write a Tail Recursive procedure to count the number of uninstantiated variables in a list. I am a little stuck, where am I going wrong.

My current query is below:

```
count([S,L],N) :- var(S), !, N+1.
count([L],N).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note: this answer presents a solution that is recursive but not *tail recursive*. For a tail recursive solution you should use an accumulator as can be shown in other answers from this question.**

As with any recursive procedure, you should add a proper base case.
In this case, it should be a clause with an empty list that returns unifies 0 with the number of uninstantiated variables:

```
count([], 0).
```

Check the clause you've written. It takes as input a list of two elements instead of a list represented as a Head item and a tail list, and it really does nothing with N:

```
count([Head|Tail], M):- 
    var(Head), 
    !, 
    count(Tail, N), 
    M is N+1.
```

And finally, you should also add a clause to deal with the case when the first item of the list *is not* an uninstantiated variable:

```
count([_|Tail], N):- count(Tail, N).
```

Comment: This is not a tail recursion because the recursive call `count(Tail,N)` is followed by a further goal `M is N+1`.

Comment: @Jini: you are right!. I oversaw the "tail recursive" part of the question, I just fixed OP code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tail recursion for counting variables in a list. It uses the technique of accumulators:

```
count(L, N) :- count(L, 0, N).     % L=list, N=count, 0=value of the sum accumulator S
count([], S, S) :- !.              % the innermost call, the accumulator S (2nd arg) "copied" to final result (3rd arg)
count([H| T], S, N):- var(H), !, S1 is S+1, count(T, S1, N). % increase accumulator if H is var
count([H| T], S, N):- count(T, S, N).    % keep accumulator if H is not var
```

No calls follow the last recursive calls in all clauses.

Comment: I included `nonvar()` on my non-variable case rule, whereas you have left it off.  I assume this is because rule order will always match the first rule that fits first, so those rules are order sensitive I imagine.  The `nonvar()` call probably slows it down.

Comment: The `nonvar()` call slows it down and is not needed if we accept that the rules are in the given order. With `nonvar()` no cuts are needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no recursion here, because in order to have recursion, you must define something in terms of itself - you'll notice an absence of the `count/2` rule on the right hand side in your code.

```
% two paths, variable and non-variable
% and a base case to start the count
count([S|L], N) :- var(S), !, count(L, N0),  N is N0+1.
count([S|L], N) :- nonvar(S), !, count(L, N).
count([], 0).
```

Alternatively, this can be done simply with `findall/3`.

```
count_alt(L, N) :- findall(S, (member(S, L), var(S)), D), length(D, N).
```

Comment: The solution `count(...)` is not a tail recursion because the recursive call `count(L,N0)` is followed by a further goal `N is N0+1`.

Comment: @Jiri: Noted, quite right.  That was why I +1 your answer.  I think this non-accumulator version is neater, due to less clauses.  But the accumulator version is about twice the speed (120% slower - I ran some profiles), the `findall/3` version is about 50% slower than the accumulator.

Comment: Orbling: The non-accumulator is surely the obvious Prolog solution - but a tail recursion was asked. Thank you for letting me know about your perf tests and for your vote :) !

Comment: @Jiri: Rereading my comment, it is poorly ordered, the accumulator version is more than twice the speed of the `count` method above, that method is 120% greater than the accumulator - it could've been read the other way round, hence the clarification. (For reference, those tests were based on a few repeats of a 4 million element list, half variables, 2.3s avg for accumulator, couldn't make the list any bigger without stack overflow on all versions on my machine.  With no variables, speeds were very close together.)